# Trying to pick the best option between multiple scenarios

Tags: probability

So this one is a bit of a puzzle, I've tried attacking it with simple probability but I think I'm probably missing a trick.

I'm looking to get a home loan. Based on the percentage that I'm going to contribute, I will be paying Insurance. The more I contribute, the less the insurance costs. This insurance cost will be added to the total loan.

I'm also fairly confident that I'll be able to refinance the loan in 9 months (I must wait 9 months) because I've bought the house for less than another bank values it. This other bank will lend me 20% of the total value that they think the house is worth.

If I do refinance the loan, the higher the percentage I contribute now, the more I'll be able to draw out as equity after refinancing as it will reduce the amount I pay for insurance and therefore minimise the size of the loan I'm about to take out. **The goal of this exercise is to maximise the amount of Total Equity I have access to.**

Now, the tricky part is that there's probably a 65-80% likelihood that the new bank will accept my refinance. There's probably also a 20% likelihood that the new bank will reduce their valuation.

I can contribute less to the loan now, therefore guaranteeing that I have access to the money now however I will be paying more in insurance, therefore meaning the total equity I will potentially have access to is lower. Or I can contribute the maximum amount and hope that the refinance goes through, therefore maximizing the amount of equity I have access to in 9 months time but that entails some risk. I can also contribute any percentage in between. This is complicated by the fact that insurance costs are lumpy and not consistent. Please see table below:

```
Contribtion Insurance Payable   Equity Now  Equity Later    Total Equity
13.60%      14,278              0.0         123,347.0       123,346.7
13%         14,386              6,832.4     116,406.0       123,238.1
12%         15,284              17,232.4    105,108.0       122,340.6
11.99%      19,862              17,336.4    100,426.0       117,762.3
11.5%       19,973              22,432.4    95,219.0        117,651.7
11%         20,086              27,632.4    89,906.0        117,538.9
10.5%       22,805              32,832.4    81,987.0        114,819.8
10%         22,932              38,032.4    76,660.0        114,692.4
9%          34,922              48,432.4    54,270.0        102,702.2
8%          36,645              58,832.4    42,147.0        100,979.0
7%          38,011              69,232.4    30,381.0        99,613.4
6%          42,721              79,632.4    15,271.0        94,903.3
5.25%       44,442              87,432.4    5,750.0         93,182.9
```

Some thoughts around this would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Try posting this on money.stackexchange as well

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'd like to get a pure math brain on this one. I think this is less of a finance related question and more of a probability question as it's not so much about the strategy, it's more about the variables

Comment: I suggest you to give 2-3 examples in different scenarios where you choose different contribution (I guess this is the variable you can control) and will have different result, base on the bank have accept your refinancing request or not. By showing the calculations in these scenario can help us better to understand the problem.

Comment: The table at the bottom of the post shows the data, with each row representing a different contribution in the form of a %. It's not well formatted for a mobile device, which I'm now finding out.